# Sorting by self column in perf report

Tags: linux, perf

How do I sort by `self` column in `perf report` output?

```
$ perf --version
perf version 4.0.8-300.fc22.x86_64

$ uname -a
Linux marko-desktop 4.0.8-300.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jul 10 21:04:56 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Data was callected with

```
$ perf record -g -p $(pidof node)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default, `perf` receives the `--children` parameter which creates the "children overhead view". As a consequence, you can switch back to a "self overhead" view by simply specifying the `--no-children` switch

```
perf report --no-children
```

There is a discussion on this topic in the man page `man perf-report`

Comment: Only the recent man page has this discussion. My version doesn't event mention --no-children (only --children). The answer is correct, thank you!

Comment: Will `--no-children` option work with `perf top -g` command? Fresh man page is at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-top.1.html